# How do I create a spring .Net standalone object of type Int32 defined in the IOC context file?

Tags: c#, spring.net

Kind of a simple newbie question...I see how I can create a string object, but how would I create an int object?

Here is the xml code fragment from my context file:

```
<object id="myString" type="System.String">
  <constructor-arg value="foo" />    
</object>
<object id="myInt" type="System.Int32">
   <<<**** how do I set this ****>>>>
</object>
```

Comment: If you want to this to be able to inject some configuration values, then you should consider using the [`PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-placeholderconfigurer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<object id="MyInt" type="System.Int32" factory-method="Copy">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
    <value>123</value>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<object id="MyInt" type="System.Int32" factory-method="Parse">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
    <value>123</value>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

For creating an object of primitive type System.Int32, you must use the **factory-method="Parse"**. The attribute factory-method="Copy" doesn't works because it not exists in the type System.Int32 and you have to use a static method to do it.